Github cache action: Content-Length not found on blob response
My software includes a third-party library which rarely changes and takes 8 minutes to build, so I figured I can speed up the pipeline by caching the build output. I have the following github workflow cache action:
        - name: Cache third-party libraries
          id: cache-libs
          uses: actions/cache@v3
          with:
            path: Path\to\libs
            key: "test-key"

On the first build, the "Cache third-party libraries" step fails to find the cache, which is expected:
Run actions/cache@v3
Cache not found for input keys: test-key

After the build, I see that the cache is created in "Post Cache third-party libraries" step:
6s
Post job cleanup.
"C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\tar.exe" --posix -cf cache.tzst --exclude cache.tzst -P -C C:/GitHub/RUNNER-1/_work/project/project --files-from manifest.txt --force-local --use-compress-program "zstd -T0"
Cache Size: ~13 MB (13645556 B)
Cache saved successfully
Cache saved with key: test-key

I can see the cache entry when I visit my_repo/actions/caches.
However, when I restart the workflow, restoring the cache fails:
Run actions/cache@v3
Warning: Failed to restore: Content-Length not found on blob response
Cache not found for input keys: test-key

What does this error mean exactly, and is there a way to fix it?
EDIT: I have also tried to trigger the save action directly after the build (as described here), but the behavior is the same: the save step works, but on a re-run the cache fetch fails with "Content-Length not found on blob response" message.

What about actions/cache@v4? Using v4 causes the same issue?

@Azeem I get the same error message with  cache@v4 as well. For the record, I have manually removed all caches before switching from v3 to v4.

Right. Have you checked the already filed issues on its repo? Found anything related?

BTW, you can have a separate repo for that third-party lib and use its build artifacts from releases instead of having this as part of this repo.

@Azeem, sure, putting the build result on artifactory is my backup plan. I would prefer to get the cache working though. First, it's easy to guarantee the same compiler is used for both the library and the app. Second, if a project needs a custom version of the library, people can just make the change and commit. I won't have to explain to them how artifactory works.

Sure, that makes sense. If it's an open source project, you may add its link in the question. If not, an MCVE would be helpful to reproduce and fix your issue.

The reason for "Content-Length not found on blob response" is that caches are disabled on our GitHub Enterprise Server, as I just found out. The confusing part is that the error only appears when restoring a cache, and now when it is created.
For now, I just installed ccache alongside the compiler, which helps to speed up repetitive builds of the same source files.
